# maven-glassfish-plugin tries to start the domain when it is already started

Tags: glassfish, maven, maven-3, maven-glassfish-plugin

I have just started using maven-glassfish-plugin. I got the start-domain goal working. However when I try to execute the deploy goal, the plugin thinks that the domain is not started and tries to restart it - this obviously fails. See log below:

```
> mvn glassfish:start-domain
[INFO] --- maven-glassfish-plugin:2.1:start-domain (default-cli) @ arquillian-sample ---
[INFO] Deprecated syntax, instead use:
[INFO] asadmin --passwordfile C:\apps\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain-passwords --interactive=false --user admin --echo --terse=false start-domain [options] ...
[INFO] asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 --user admin --passwordfile C:\apps\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain-passwords --interactive=false --echo=true --terse=false start-domain --debug=true --domaindir C:\apps\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish\domains --help=false --upgrade=false --verbose=false domain1
[INFO] Waiting for DAS to start ...
[INFO] Started domain: domain1
[INFO] Domain location: C:\apps\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish\domains\domain1
[INFO] Log file: C:\apps\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log
[INFO] Admin port for the domain: 4848
[INFO] Debug port for the domain: 9009
[INFO] Command start-domain executed successfully.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

> mvn glassfish:deploy
[INFO] --- maven-glassfish-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) @ arquillian-sample ---
[INFO] Domain domain1 isn't started. Starting it for you.
[INFO] Deprecated syntax, instead use:
[INFO] asadmin --passwordfile C:\apps\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain-passwords --interactive=false --user admin --echo --terse=false start-domain [options] ...
[INFO] asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 --user admin --passwordfile C:\apps\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain-passwords --interactive=false --echo=true --terse=false start-domain --debug=true --domaindir C:\apps\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish\domains --help=false --upgrade=false --verbose=false domain1
[INFO] There is a process already using the admin port 4848 -- it probably is another instance of a GlassFish server.
[INFO] Command start-domain failed.
[ERROR] Unable to start domain "domain1".
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

1. Why can't the plugin detect that the domain has already started?
2. Why am I getting all the "Deprecated syntax" warnings?

To workaround issue #1, I simply tried to issue the deploy goal when the server is not running. This time the deploy goal successfully started the server, but the deployment failed with the message "CLI136 Port 0 should be a numeric value". See below:

```
> mvn glassfish:deploy
[INFO] --- maven-glassfish-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) @ arquillian-sample ---
[INFO] Domain domain1 isn't started. Starting it for you.
[INFO] Deprecated syntax, instead use:
[INFO] asadmin --passwordfile C:\apps\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain-passwords --interactive=false --user admin --echo --terse=false start-domain [options] ...
[INFO] asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 --user admin --passwordfile C:\apps\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain-passwords --interactive=false --echo=true --terse=false start-domain --debug=true --domaindir C:\apps\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish\domains --help=false --upgrade=false --verbose=false domain1
[INFO] Waiting for DAS to start ...
[INFO] Started domain: domain1
[INFO] Domain location: C:\apps\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish\domains\domain1
[INFO] Log file: C:\apps\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log
[INFO] Admin port for the domain: 4848
[INFO] Debug port for the domain: 9009
[INFO] Command start-domain executed successfully.
[INFO] Command deploy failed.
[ERROR] CLI136 Port 0 should be a numeric value.
[ERROR] Deployment of S:\Projects\archfirstunf\java\trunk\examples\arquillian-sample\target\arquillian-sample.war failed.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <glassfishDirectory>${glassfish.directory}</glassfishDirectory>
        <user>admin</user>
        <passwordFile>${glassfish.directory}/domains/domain1/config/domain-passwords</passwordFile>
        <domain>
            <name>domain1</name>
        </domain>
        <components>
            <component>
                <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                <artifact>target/${project.build.finalName}.war</artifact>
            </component>
        </components>
        <debug>true</debug>
        <terse>false</terse>
        <echo>true</echo>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using the following configuration (note the `httpPort` and `adminPort` in the `domain` element):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <glassfishDirectory>${glassfish.directory}</glassfishDirectory>
        <user>admin</user>
        <passwordFile>${glassfish.directory}/domains/domain1/config/domain-passwords</passwordFile>
        <domain>
            <name>domain1</name>
            <httpPort>8080</httpPort>
            <adminPort>4848</adminPort>
        </domain>
        <components>
            <component>
                <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                <artifact>target/${project.build.finalName}.war</artifact>
            </component>
        </components>
        <debug>true</debug>
        <terse>false</terse>
        <echo>true</echo>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Without them, things weren't working as expected (although they are supposed to be optional). But starting, deploying (with or without the server started), etc just works fine for me.

PS: I don't remember if this is important but I'm using version 2.2-SNAPSHOT Of the plugin.

---

**Update:** Here is the exact configuration I use:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <configuration>
      <glassfishDirectory>${glassfish.home}</glassfishDirectory>
      <user>${domain.username}</user>
      <passwordFile>${glassfish.home}/domains/${project.artifactId}/master-password</passwordFile>
      <autoCreate>true</autoCreate>
      <debug>true</debug>
      <echo>true</echo>
      <skip>${test.int.skip}</skip>
      <domain>
        <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
        <httpPort>8080</httpPort>
        <adminPort>4848</adminPort> <!-- [ERROR] CLI136 Port 0 should be a numeric value. -->
      </domain>
      <components>
        <component>
          <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
          <!--artifact>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</artifact-->
          <artifact>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</artifact>
        </component>
      </components>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

And here is the output I get:

```
$ mvn glassfish:deploy 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building maven-glassfish-testcase Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-glassfish-plugin:2.2-SNAPSHOT:deploy (default-cli) @ maven-glassfish-testcase ---
...
[INFO] asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 --user admin --passwordfile /home/pascal/opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/maven-glassfish-testcase/master-password --interactive=false --echo=true --terse=true deploy --name maven-glassfish-testcase --force=false --precompilejsp=false --verify=false --enabled=true --generatermistubs=false --availabilityenabled=false --keepreposdir=false --keepfailedstubs=false --logReportedErrors=true --upload=false --help=false /home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/maven-glassfish-testcase/target/maven-glassfish-testcase
[INFO] Application deployed successfully with name maven-glassfish-testcase.
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

Note that I don't get any weird "deprecated" message. And things just work fine.

Adding httpPort and adminPort adds a new complication - now authentication is failing when I do the deploy (even though the same authentication is passing for the start-domain goal).

```
> mvn glassfish:start-domain
[INFO] --- maven-glassfish-plugin:2.2-SNAPSHOT:start-domain (default-cli) @ arquillian-sample ---
[INFO] Deprecated syntax, instead use:
[INFO] asadmin --passwordfile C:\apps\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain-passwords --interactive=false --user admin --echo --terse=false start-domain [options] ...
[INFO] asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 --user admin --passwordfile C:\apps\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain-passwords --interactive=false --echo=true --terse=false start-domain --debug=true --domaindir C:\apps\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish\domains --help=false --upgrade=false --verbose=false domain1
[INFO] Waiting for DAS to start ...........
[INFO] Started domain: domain1
[INFO] Domain location: C:\apps\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish\domains\domain1
[INFO] Log file: C:\apps\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log
[INFO] Admin port for the domain: 4848
[INFO] Debug port for the domain: 9009
[INFO] Command start-domain executed successfully.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

> mvn glassfish:deploy
[INFO] --- maven-glassfish-plugin:2.2-SNAPSHOT:deploy (default-cli) @ arquillian-sample ---
[INFO] Deprecated syntax, instead use:
[INFO] asadmin --port 4848 --host localhost --passwordfile C:\apps\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain-passwords --interactive=false --user admin --echo --terse=false deploy [options] ...
[INFO] Command deploy failed.
[ERROR] Authentication failed for user: admin
[ERROR] (Usually, this means invalid user name and/or password)
[ERROR] Deployment of S:\Projects\archfirstunf\java\trunk\examples\arquillian-sample\target\arquillian-sample.war failed.
[ERROR] For more detail on what might be causing the problem try running maven with the --debug option
[ERROR] or setting the maven-glassfish-plugin "echo" property to "true".
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.973s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Nov 10 01:51:04 EST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/183M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Changing version to 2.2-SNAPSHOT makes no difference. BTW the snapshot is not available in the java.net repository - I had to go here to get it:

```
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>ocean</id>
        <url>http://maven.ocean.net.au/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
```

Comment: Ok, I got it running! The problem was with the password. I am using the admin user for all operations, but apparently the master-password file does not store the admin password. I had to supply it using the <adminPassword> tag. Of course it is not ideal to keep the admin password in the pom, so I am wondering why this password is not in master-password. There are 2 other password files in the config directory too. What is the purpose of all these password files? Anyway, thanks for all your help Pascal!

Comment: @Naresh: As shown, my `passwordFile` is pointing on a *master-password* file that I generated at [domain creation time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935137/glassfish-v3-and-glassfish-maven-plugin-mac), this probably makes a difference. And now that I think again about all this, I'm not sure I'm doing the right thing, I think I'm misusing that *master-password* file. But since it works (maybe because I'm using the same password as for the *admin* password), I never really dug this topic.

Comment: Where did you get the 2.2-SNAPSHOT?  Doesn't seem to be at http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/glassfish/maven/plugin/maven-glassfish-plugin/