# Running Maven project on glassfish server

Tags: eclipse, maven, glassfish, war

I want to run web based Maven project on glassfish server. I am totally new on maven. However, i have successfully build the maven project and glassfish server is up and running also. Moreover, there is WAR file also in *target* folder but i am confused what is the next step to run that project on glassfish ?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have different options to solve this task:

1. If you are new to Eclipse I suggest to change to [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org). It comes with integrated support for application server deployments. You just add your maven (or nearly any other type of project like WAR, EJB and EAR) project and your desired application server instance (Glassfish) and you are ready: Right-click your project and choose `Deploy` and it'll get deployed to your server. NetBeans also supports hot-deployment.
2. You can deploy your WAR file manually in `GLASSFISH_ROOT/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy` and it'll get deployed if your server is running. But this is not very efficient during development.
3. If you want to stay with Eclipse you can use the [maven-glassfish-plugin](http://maven-glassfish-plugin.java.net/) or this [maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to do the deployment for you. I'm not sure which one is better but this topic is also discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956538/how-to-run-the-project-after-building-with-maven) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836317/which-maven-glassfish-plugin-to-use).